# How to kill many instances of a process at one go?

Tags: linux, unix, process, system-administration

I have several instances of a process (i.e. with a common command line). I would like to kill all of them at one go. How to achieve it?

Comment: killall is the command you are looking for: http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_killall.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Options:

1. killall
2. ps|awk|xargs kill
3. tag-and-kill in htop

Killall is super powerful, but I find it hazardous to use indiscriminately. Option 2 is awkward to use, but I often find myself in environments that don't have killall; also, leaving out the xargs bit on the first pass lets me review the condemned processes before I swing the blade. Ultimately, I usually favour htop, since it lets me pick and choose before hitting the big "k".

Comment: I was able to achieve this by ps -ef|grep <some snippet from command line>|awk '{print $2}'|xargs kill -9

Comment: @p2pnode: Ah, yes, I always forget to include awk, even when I'm using it myself. BTW, you can use just awk: `ps -ef | awk '/snippet/{print$2} | xargs ...`.

Comment: @ephemient: Nice one! I hadn't heard of pkill. The manpage also shows pgrep, which would be a good way to review processes before killing them with the same pattern.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for the `killall` command. For example:

```
killall perl
```

Would kill off all perl processes that are running on your machine. See http://linux.die.net/man/1/killall for more details.

Answer (score 1):

[`killall`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_killall.htm) will do that for you. Use `man killall` for the options but I usually do:

```
killall myProgName
```

Just be *very* careful (eg, use `ps` first to make sure it will only kill what you want).

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: killall is the answer... *IF* you're on Linux.  SysV also has a killall command, but it does a very, very different thing: it's part of the shutting-down-processes-prior-to-system-halt.  So, yes, killall's the easiest, but if you often shuttle between Linux and SysV systems, I might recommend writing up a quick script to do what you want, instead.